# Which set contains this Bionicle part? Looks like a mohawk or some sort of blade

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, bionicle

Which set contains this piece? I cant find anything. It looks like a big Bionicle mohawk.

[image: Bionicle mohawk or some sort of blade]

Answer (score 4):

This part is [20479](https://rebrickable.com/parts/20479/large-figure-weapon-axe-skull-warrior/179/) (Large Figure Weapon Axe, Skull Warrior):

[image: Part photo]

It is present in 3 sets from 2015:

- [70793-1 - Skull Basher](https://rebrickable.com/sets/70793-1/skull-basher/?inventory=1#parts)
- [70794-1 - Skull Scorpio](https://rebrickable.com/sets/70794-1/skull-scorpio/?inventory=1#parts)
- [70795-1 - Mask Maker vs. Skull Grinder](https://rebrickable.com/sets/70795-1/mask-maker-vs-skull-grinder/?inventory=1#parts)

It is used as a blade, weapon, or sharp edge in these sets:

[image: Set photo]